# Is there any way to have a nested "ActionGroup" under another "ActionGroup" in kivy (ActionBar)?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, kivy

1. **Main ActionBar:**

   - It contains an `ActionView`, which is a container for organizing action buttons.
   - The first item is an `ActionPrevious` button, which might represent a navigation back button.
   - Then, there's an `ActionButton` labeled 'File'.
2. **ActionGroup for "Students":**

   - This is an `ActionGroup` under the main ActionBar.
   - It contains an `ActionGroup` for "Assessment" and an `ActionButton` for 'Students'.
3. **ActionGroup for "Assessment" (submenu under "Students"):**

   - This is a nested `ActionGroup` under the "Students" group.
   - It contains four `ActionButton` items: 'Weekly Test', 'Mid Term Exams', 'End of Term Exams', and 'Mock Exams'.
4. **Remaining ActionButtons:**

   - There are two additional `ActionButton` items labeled 'Setup' and 'Reports' directly under the main ActionBar.

In summary, I have a hierarchical structure where "Assessment" is a submenu under "Students," and "Weekly Test" to "Mock Exams" are submenu items under "Assessment." The other buttons like 'File,' 'Setup,' and 'Reports' are direct items under the main ActionBar.

The big problem is that the four submenu items do not appear when I click on "Assessment".

```
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint: .3, None
                height: "25dp"

                # The action bar
                ActionBar:
                    pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                    height: "25dp"
                    background_color: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1

                    ActionView:
                        use_separator: True
                        ActionPrevious:
                            with_previous: False
                        
                        ActionButton:
                            text: 'File'

                        ActionGroup:
                            text: "Students"
                            mode: "spinner"

                            ActionGroup:
                                text: "Assessment"
                                mode: "spinner"

                                ActionButton:
                                    text: "Weekly Test"
                                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                                ActionButton:
                                    text: "Mid Term Exams"
                                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                                ActionButton:
                                    text: "End of Term Exams"
                                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                                ActionButton:
                                    text: "Mock Exams"
                                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1

                        ActionButton:
                            text: 'Setup'
                        ActionButton:
                            text: 'Reports'
`
```

I want the four submenu items to appear when the "Assessment" is clicked but unfortunately, I can't get it worked now.